# VC++ 9 QT Project, Convert To Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, c

Their is a project I would like to start working on but the problem is I use Linux and the project is based off windows. (VC++ v9) I would like to convert it to Eclipse CDT but qmake and different includes are driving me mad.

[Project Repo](https://bitbucket.org/ronanpaixao/pirateship)

1 - I downloaded Eclipse Indigo CDT
2 - Downloaded the latest QT ( qt.nokia.com / downloads )
3 - Integrate it into Eclipse ( qt.nokia.com / developer / eclipse-integration/ )
4 - Download qextserialport ( sourceforge.net / projects / qextserialport/ )

Can anybody help me get this project into Eclipse so I do not need to rely on a makefile and can build it with the Eclipse menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [tutorial](http://assorted-experience.blogspot.com/2008/05/setting-up-cqt-project-on-eclipse-under.html) to do exactly what you're asking. It's geared for OS X, but the same principles would apply.

Comment: Thanks! I was not running with the -project switch so some of the .pro files where not generating